# Swagger Try it out button not working (Swashbuckle issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I added Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.4.0 to my VS2017 project
following along on Pluralsight's Play by Play course.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:51806/swagger/`  I have the swagger UI.
When I click on the "Try it out" button the button changes to "Cancel" but nothing else happens.

I have tried each response content type

Swagger support forum indicates this is a Swashbuckle issue.

[Update]

I just did not realise that the Execute was a link

[image: as shown here]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors in the browser console

Comment: Is there button  "Execute"? Did you try other browsers?

Comment: Does this prove that , UI design of Swagger is not appropriate (think) ?

Comment: Ah it just shows the design was not intuitive for a particular newbie (me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But after pressing the button "Try it out", nothing should happen, only display "Execute" button

[image]

Comment: Thank you, oh dear, lol, I updated the question to show my ignorance!

Comment: Glad to have been of help